# System.OutOfMemoryException in SharpDevelop

Tags: c#, excel, exception, out-of-memory

I am not sure why I am getting a `System.OutOfMemoryException` in SharpDevelop for my program in C#. My program opens up an Excel worksheet and processes some of the data in the worksheet to check for duplicates.

Here is the complete Exception error message:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: See inner exception(s) for details. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.OutOfMemoryException: Not enough storage is available to complete this operation. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000E (E_OUTOFMEMORY))
   at static Object NetOffice.Invoker.PropertyGet(NetOffice.COMObject comObject, System.String name, System.Object[] paramsArray)
   at Object NetOffice.ExcelApi.Range.get_Value()
   at System.Void excelApp.Program.markDuplicates() in c:\Users\HP\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\excelApp\excelApp\Program.cs:line 80
   at static System.Void excelApp.Program.Main(System.String[] args) in c:\Users\HP\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\excelApp\excelApp\Program.cs:line 41
```

Here is my complete program:

It is pointing at the following line in the `markDuplicates()` method:
Line 80:

`Object[,] valuesArray = (Object[,])tableRange.Value;`

I have no idea why I am getting this exception.

I am using .NET Framework 4.5.1.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Input.Manipulations;
using NetOffice.ExcelApi;
using NetOffice.ExcelApi.Enums;
using Excel = NetOffice.ExcelApi.Application;

namespace excelApp
{
    class Program
    {

        Excel excelApplication;
        Workbook workbook;
        Worksheet sheet;

        HashSet<int> mpanHashCodeList;  


        [STAThreadAttribute]
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            p.openWorkSheet(@"C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Book1.xlsx", 2);    
            p.markDuplicates();      
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }


        private void openWorkSheet(string path, int worksheet)
        {

            excelApplication = new Excel
            {
                Visible = true,
                ScreenUpdating = true
            };

            try
            {
                workbook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(path);
                sheet = (Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets[worksheet];
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File does not exist");
            }
        }



        private void markDuplicates()
        {

           Range range = sheet.Cells[2,2];
           Range rngLastCell = range.get_End(XlDirection.xlToRight)
                                       .get_End(XlDirection.xlDown);


           // holds the range of cells in the worksheet
           Range tableRange = sheet.Range(range, rngLastCell);

           // holds all the values of the range of cells in the worksheet
           Object[,] valuesArray = (Object[,])tableRange.Value;

           mpanHashCodeList = new HashSet<int>();



           int count = 0;
           for(var i = 1; i <= valuesArray.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
           {      


           // create a new string for each row             
           var rowIdBuilder = new StringBuilder(10);


                   for(var j = 1; j <= valuesArray.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
                   {      
                       switch(j)
                       {
                           case 1:
                               rowIdBuilder.Append(valuesArray[i,j].ToString());   
                               break;
                           case 3:
                               rowIdBuilder.Append(valuesArray[i,j].ToString());  
                               break;
                           case 4:
                               rowIdBuilder.Append(valuesArray[i,j].ToString()); 
                               break;
                           case 6:
                               rowIdBuilder.Append(valuesArray[i,j].ToString());
                               break;        
                       }       
                   }



                  Console.WriteLine(rowIdBuilder.ToString());
                   int hashcode = rowIdBuilder.ToString().GetHashCode();


                   if(mpanHashCodeList.Contains(hashcode))
                   {
                       count++;     
                       mpanHashCodeList.Remove(hashcode);
                   }           
                   else 
                   {    
                       mpanHashCodeList.Add(hashcode);

                   }


           }

           Console.WriteLine(count + " duplicates found");

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite common for native code to return error code 0x8007000E (E_OUTOFMEMORY), which is then mapped to OutOfMemory exception in managed code. For example, this is common returned when a native heap allocations fails, or a handle allocation fails.

Such problem is best diagnosed with mixed mode debugging in Visual Studio. Pros would normally use tools like WinDbg/cdb for such tasks with the right symbols properly resolved.

In short: no simple answer. Dirty work expected.

Comment: So what am I supposed to do exactly? I can't use Visual Studio because it won't recognise the libraries as I have already tried, can't debug my code on VS. How do I get around this in SharpDevelop?